# jQuery only clones and inserts once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form on my website to upload pictures to a gallery. 
I want the user to be able to add and delete form fields and followed this great tutorial to achieve this: http://davidlesches.com/blog/rails-nested-forms-using-jquery-and-simpleform

My javascript looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".duplicatable-nested-form").size() > 0){
        nestedForm = $(".duplicatable-nested-form").last().clone();
    }
    $(".duplicate-nested-form").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        lastNestedForm = $(".duplicatable-nested-form").last();
        count = $(lastNestedForm).find("input").attr("id");
        console.log(count);
        newNestedForm = $(nestedForm);
        formsOnPage = $(".duplicatable-nested-form").size();

        $(newNestedForm).find("label").each(function(){
            oldLabel = $(this).attr("for");
            newLabel = oldLabel.replace(new RegExp(/_[0-9]+_/), "_" + formsOnPage + "_");
            $(this).attr("for", newLabel);
        });

        $(newNestedForm).find("select,input").each(function(){
            oldId = $(this).attr("id");
            newId = oldId.replace(new RegExp(/_[0-9]+_/), "_" + formsOnPage + "_");
            $(this).attr("id", newId);

            oldName = $(this).attr("name");
            newName = oldName.replace(new RegExp(/\[[0-9]+\]/), "[" + formsOnPage + "]");
            $(this).attr("name", newName);
        });

        $(newNestedForm).insertAfter(lastNestedForm);
    });

    $(".duplicatable-nested-form").on("click", ".remove-duplicate-nested-form", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".duplicatable-nested-form").slideUp().remove();
    });
});
```

It works just fine, but only once. So when the user clicks the button to add a field, a `newNestedForm` is created and added to the DOM. After that when the button is clicked javascript will still make a `newNestedForm`, but it's not added to the `DOM`. Any idea why this is? Or how I could debug this a bit better?

EDIT: this is how my view looks of the form

```
<%= form_for(@gallery, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :pictures %><br />
    <ul>
        <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
            <li class="clearfix duplicatable-nested-form">
                 <% if p.object.image.length > 1 %>
                     <%= image_tag(p.object.image)  %>
                 <% end %>
                 <%= p.file_field :image %>
                 <%= p.text_field :title %>
                 <% if p.object.new_record? %>
                     <br />
                     <%= link_to "Remove", "", remote: true, class: "remove-duplicate-nested-form" %>
                 <% else %>
                     <%= link_to "Remove", gallery_picture_path(@gallery, p.object), method: :delete, remote: true, class: "remove-duplicate-nested-form" %>
                     <%= p.hidden_field :id %>
                 <% end %>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= link_to "Add another picture", "", class: "duplicate-nested-form"%>
```

Comment: need to delegate event handlers to account for future elements. Delegate the first click handler

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but do you mean writing something like ` $(".form").on("click", ".duplicate-nested-form", function(event){` ?
Because that doesn't change anything to the issue. FYI, I added some more info to my opening question